# Why am I getting badimagexception?

Tags: c#

I have a code sample that's supposed to detect my canon 550d digital camera so I can control the camera from the pc.
I just downloaded the source files from here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17344/A-wrapper-for-the-canon-CDSDK-and-PRSDK-for-remote?fid=379739&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Quick&spc=Relaxed&fr=1#xx0xx

I created a new project in Visual Studio 2012 Pro; my pc is running Windows 8 64bit.
I added all the .cs files and also copied all the dll files I downloaded from the Canon website after registering.

The first time I ran the program and clicked on the connect button, I got an exception that a dll is missing. Since there is no way to add the dlls as referenced, I copied them to the Debug directory.

The missing dll was PRSDK.dll, so I found and downloaded the dll, and copied it.

Now when I click on the connect button, I get a different exception:

BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

The exception is in the file Camera.cs, on the line:

```
err = prAPI.PR_StartSDK();
```

I googled for this exception and found that some people have changed the project platform and target to x86, so I tried it - I tried changing it to x86, x64, AnyCpu, everything, but it didn't help.

Maybe the PRSDK.dll file is old and not useable in Windows 8?

This is a link to my project/solution in my SkyDrive, if someone can please download it and try to run it on his machine and maybe find a solution?

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=EB1C71C44C3976D5!201&authkey=!AErpIgyllPAgH9w

The project called: Canon_Camera_Control

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I downloaded your project and found the problem.

**Your DLL files are wrong!**

They are not even DLL actually, they are html files with the .dll extension. Apparently you tried to download them from some webpage but didn't succeed.

Try redownloading it or obtain the SDK from official (Canon) sources.

Comment: That is hilarious. Shame on myself for not downloading his solution and looking at the dlls. I get that occasionally with downloaded mp3s that were actually 404'd pages with mp3 extensions; never seen it on a dll download. :D (Though, kinda lame of .net that it doesn't distinguish between "tried to load this dll but it was the wrong format", vs "tried to load this dll, and what the crap did you give me, this isn't even a dll!")

Comment: Carko which files are not .dll ? I did properties on PRSDK.dll and on DPPDLL.dll for example this two dll files and i see in the properties:  Application extension (.dll) can you please specify which files are not .dll i mean not realy dll and how did you manage to find that they are not dll so i will know to do it in the future ?

Comment: Carko do you mean this two files that are not realy dll ? PRLIB.dll and PRSDK.dll

Comment: @YaronCohenMinz Yes those two. I loaded them into the dependency walker and it said no PE signature was found. Renamed them to .txt and opened them up in the notepad and saw the HTML in there

Answer (score 1):

You must have missed something. The error is definitely the one that states that the platform of your project and the one of the external dll don't match.

Maybe you changed the "Active solution platform" but not the "Project platform".

Comment: Tried anything any platforms and targets: x86 then x64 then all platforms. changed in any places nothing worked. Can someone please download the project from my skydrive and try it and maybe to find out the problem/solution ?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that tripped me up regarding exactly this, not too long ago: check to make sure (Build->Configuration Manager) that in your solution, when you change the solution's platform to x86, the platform of your actual project in that dialog is actually set to x86. Sometimes VS is dumb, and leaves it as Any CPU (great if all your code and all your third-party dlls are managed, not so great if you're calling, for instance, a wrapper to an unmanaged camera dll.)

It's possible something totally unrelated is going on, but every time I've seen that error it's because you're running as x86/x64 and loading an unmanaged dll that's of the other platform type.

Answer (score 0):

One reason is that you might be trying to load a 32-bit assembly into a 64-bit application. This can happen when you have the **Any CPU** platform selected.

On [my blog](http://samuelhaddad.com/?s=bad%20image%20exception&submit=Ok) I outline this issue more with screenshots on how you can change it

but basically you can set your project it always compile in 32 bit mode.